# Unable to keep header rows and columns on each page SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

For some reason I am unable to keep header on each page. I have similar report and all I did is changed in a properties "`RepeatColumnHeaders`" and "`RepeadRowHeaders`" to `true`. 
[image]
But for some reason with this report it doesnt work that way. I keep playint around in Advanced by changing `RepeatOnNewPage` to True and `KeepWithGroup` to After but it gives me an error:
[image]

Comment: set RepeatColumnHeaders and RepeadRowHeaders to false .

Comment: It was set to false all that time. What am I missing?